# Unity Glitches but does not show any errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity Does not do anything and my Game audio does not work but no errors in the console.

I think my code might be causing this.

Here is my Code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CompDel : MonoBehaviour
{
        public Text TimeText;

        public float Timer = 70;

        public string currentScene = "";
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            Timer = Timer - 1 * Time.deltaTime;


            if (Timer < 40)
            {
                this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled = false;
                

            };

            
            if (Timer < 0 && currentScene != "AESCENE")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("AESCENE");
                currentScene = "AESCENE";
            } 
            else if (Timer < 30 && currentScene != "MainScene")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
                currentScene = "MainScene";
            } 
            else if (Timer < 40 && currentScene != "SSScene")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("SSScene");
                currentScene = "SSScene";
            }

            if (Timer < 0)
            {
                this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled = false;
                this.GetComponent<RR1>().enabled = false;

            };
        } 
}
```

Here is what happens when i run my game:

https://youtu.be/zwEANZhVeV8

this is the vide

Reply soon

:D

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service, you don't get to make time demands.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a SceneManager that is a [singleton](http://www.unitygeek.com/unity_c_singleton/#:%7E:text=Singleton%20is%20a%20basic%20Design,multiple%20times%20during%20a%20game.) script, the `loadscene` method is getting called over and over again, once the scene loads the timer resets and the script starts from 70 again. You will have to make a script that attach it to an empty `gameobject` and make it go inside `DontDestroyOnLoad`. Please read more about using singletons.

Why is there a semicolon at the end of your `if`?

```
if (Timer < 40)
{
    this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled = false;
};
```

and at the last if `statement` too.

You can clean your code a little:

```
if (Timer < 0)
{
    if(currentScene != "AESCENE")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("AESCENE");
        currentScene = "AESCENE";
    }
    else
    {
        this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled = false;
        this.GetComponent<RR1>().enabled = false;
    }
} 
else if (Timer < 30 && currentScene != "MainScene")
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
    currentScene = "MainScene";
} 
else if (Timer < 40 && currentScene != "SSScene")
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("SSScene");
    currentScene = "SSScene";
}
```

Comment: Erm.I think It is slightly fixed now But it still is glitching

Comment: Did you implement the singleton script?